Cast a string name to model name which already exists in knockout JS
I am working on a dynamic validation setting in Knockout JS. I blocked by one scenario, I am getting viewmodel name as string from db with control id. This model name is a string name like “testModel.name”. This model already exists, I need to cast the string name to a model and need to set the required validation for this model, something like.
var myModel = “testModel.name”;

myModel = ko.observable<string>("").extend({
    required: {
        message: "name is required."  });

Is it possible?

Does this answer your question? "Variable" variables in JavaScript and Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path

Thanks. I didn't get any clue from above. Because here model already exists but in runtime variable having it's name only as string. I need to convert this string name to viewmodel, then only I can extend it's property.
